# Unable to activate virtual environment using .bat file

Tags: python, powershell, python-venv

All of the sudden task scheduler stopped working.
Digging into details, seems like batch file is not activating virtual environment for some reason.

```
Manually running the below command in powershell works fine.
.\.venv\Scripts\Activate.ps1
```

However, manually running .bat file gives me "ModuleNotFoundError" error, because venv is not activated.

```
set OdenImports=OdenImports
start "C:\Users\path\MyReports\.venv\Scripts\python.exe" && "C:\Users\path\MyReports\main.py" %1 %OdenImports%
```

Why all of the sudden it stopped working and how can I fix it?

Comment: may want to tag the batch community in here as well (`[batch-file]`,`[cmd]`)

Comment: The content of your batch file suggests that it never worked: in a batch file, `start` launches an _independent process, in a new window_ by default, whereas what follows `&&` is executed by the _current_ process.

Comment: @mklement0 Thank you. 
I removed `Start`, replaced `python.exe` with `activate.bat` and it works.